# How to restrict Function Call Arity to 0 in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am using the latest version of flow `"flow-bin": "0.54.1"` and I need to make sure that a function cannot receive any parameters
so in my case I would like to enforce an arity of 0.

> A function’s arity is the number of arguments it expects.

- Does flow handle this scenario by default (for my testing no), or should I add information about the arity allowed manually, if yes a how?

My code:

```
const location = ():{locationId: number, geo: Array<number>, isFetching:boolean} => {
  return {
    locationId: 5128581, // nyc usa
    geo: [-74.006, 40.7143],
    isFetching: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Can’t you find out if Flow handles this scenario by default by trying `location('foo')`?

Comment: I have tried to test the default behavior but passing location('foo') does NOT return any errors.

Comment: I just tried it in flow.org/try and it did return an error. If you want anyone to help you, you'll need to provide a reproducible example. https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBANiYBDKBLcMC8MAUBKALgG8Fk1wBJAEwJjAFcBbAIwFMAnAGhgHNWRaAQXbskATwA8DFhwB83VBABirKMAAWqMDwLMQIOKyRgAvllkwiAKBgx2q+uzCWbt+IhTow1WgFYAjABMABy+wf7cAPSRdGLAMPQQSK62fAIwANoAtADsACwAdAAMRQBs3HlFBTn+eQDMALqcKTCKKmqa2rQAZkhwEKyuJlbDVqSe4DgA5N36U3gA3EA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow handles this properly and will present an error if you pass unexpected arguments to a function call. I pasted your code into [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBANiYBDKBLcMC8MAUBKALgG8Fk1wBJAEwJjAFcBbAIwFMAnAGhgHNWRaAQXbskATwA8DFhwB83VBABirKMAAWqMDwLMQIOKyRgAvllkwiAKBgx2q+uzCWbt+IhTow1WgFYAjABMABy+wf7cAPSRdGLAMPQQSK62fAIwANoAtADsACwAdAAMRQBs3HlFBTn+eQDMALqcKTCKKmqa2rQAZkhwEKyuJlbDVqSe4DgAROqscAhTeADcQA), along with a call to your function with one argument:

```
location("hello");
```

And I get an error:

```
9: location("hello");
            ^ unused function argument
1: const location = ():{locationId: number, geo: Array<number>, isFetching:boolean} => {
                    ^ function expects no arguments
```